# Python Check only outputting a string

Tags: python, types

```
num = input("Enter Something:")
    print(type(num))
```

for some reason when running this code, or any alternative version even without text (string), it still outputs a string.

```
<class 'str'>
```

is there any way to check for all types like expected? e.g str and int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that input() returns a string, so the datatype of num will always be a string. If you want to look at that string and determine whether it's a string, int, or float, you can try converting the string to those datatypes explicitly and check for errors.

Here's an example of one such check:

```
def check_user_input(input):
try:
    # Convert it into integer
    val = int(input)
    print("Input is an integer number. Number = ", val)
except ValueError:
    try:
        # Convert it into float
        val = float(input)
        print("Input is a float  number. Number = ", val)
    except ValueError:
        print("No.. input is not a number. It's a string")
```

I got this example here where there's a more thorough explanation: https://pynative.com/python-check-user-input-is-number-or-string/

Here is a solution based on that for your problem specifically:

```
def convert_input(input):
    try:
        # Convert it into integer
        val = int(input)
        return val
    except ValueError:
        try:
            # Convert it into float
            val = float(input)
            return val
        except ValueError:
            return input

num = input("Enter Something:")
num = convert_input(num)
print(type(num))
```

Comment: @umfhero no problem! If your question is answered, please accept the answer so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Input always returns string. If you want some other type you have to cast.
For example:

```
input_int = int(input("Enter something"))
```

Comment: So there is no way to input multiple? was just wondering if I could avoid doing a task without loads of if and elif statements

Comment: @umfhero You can input multiple space-separated numbers then `split` them, or just use a loop that calls `input` repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that, the **default input is set to return string**. To make this clear, do refer to the following example:

```
>>> number_input = input("Input a number: ")
Input a number: 17
>>> number = number_input
>>> print(type(number))
<class 'str'>
```

Python defines the `number_input` as a string, because `input` is by default a string. And if python recognizes `number_input` as string, variable `number` must also be a string, even though it is purely numbers.

To set `number` as a int, you need to specify the input as `int(input("Input a number: "))`. And of course, if you want to input float, just change the data type to float input.

But answering your question, you can't print `<class 'str'>` and `<class 'int'>` at the same time.

Comment: See I understood that and thank you for clarifying! I was just asking if there was any condition to take both. Thank you again tho.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you type `input()`, python run it as `string` data-type so you can change or actually limit it by usage of `int()`

```
integer_number = int(input("only numbers accepted: "))
```